# calling JavaScript function defined in an extended String objects gets error object has no method

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am using [Parse.com Cloud Code](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code) where I am trying to singularize words.
I found an extension of String class [Inflection-js](https://code.google.com/p/inflection-js/) that does it with functions like:

```
String.singularize(singular)
```

But when I run it I get:

```
Result: TypeError: Object doors has no method 'singularize'
```

Here is the how I use Inflection-js

```
var express = require('express');

require('cloud/inflection.js');

Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Comment", function(request, response) {

    var test = "doors";
    console.log(test.singularize());

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is Inflection-js doesn't support AMD so it won't work with RequireJS use this port of it instead: https://github.com/simonwex/inflection-js